# Agricultural Land Classification from ArcGIS Online not working?

Tags: arcgis-online, united-kingdom

When I add the Agricultural land classification (ALC) map from ArcGIS Online, the layer in the table of contents loads, however the actual map doesn't.

I really need to ALC for the Humber Region, UK for my final year project, and I can't find any other downloads which actually work.

Comment: You haven't provided a URL to the service. This should be a bug report to the provider. Bug reports are not appropriate for GIS SE.

Comment: Amy use the download service here for your area of interest https://environment.data.gov.uk/DefraDataDownload/?mapService=NE/AgriculturalLandClassificationProvisionalEngland&Mode=spatial

Comment: Make sure the basemap doesn't have the "display only when at particular map scales" set. Check the layer properties not at the top-level in the table of contents, but one down. Right-click, open properties, check general tab and look in the Scale Range section.